# Autorefresh webview in flutter

Tags: flutter, webview, refresh

I want to make a really basic app. Just load a website and refresh every let's say 1 hour. I use webview, and i've seen i can do this with timer. My webview code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

Timer timer;


void main() => runApp(WebViewExample());

class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
}



class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
      initialUrl: 'https://mywebsite.com',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do it with timer, so what is your problem?

Comment: i am completely new to app development, so i dont know how to implement the timer thing

Answer (score 0):

```
timer(){

Timer _timer = new Timer.periodic(
              oneDecimal,
                  (Timer timer) =>
                  setState(() {
                    if (_start < 100) {
                      _timer.cancel();
                    } else {
                      _start = _start - 100;
                      callRefresh();
                    }
                  }));
}

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer();
  }
```

Comment: Undefined name 'oneDecimal'.
_start, _timer, and callRefresh()
is any library missing?

Comment: callRefresh means call what function you want

Comment: ok, but oneDecimal'. _start, _timer are also missing..

Comment: define them in state